# Error when trying to update Extensions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to update Extensions in Visual Studio 2010, and I am suddenly getting errors. I open the extension manager and let it load the list of updates. I select one, and click Update, but I get a dialog with an error. One of two errors occurs depending on which extension I am trying to update.

For example, trying to update Nuget gets me:

```
Value cannot be null
Parameter name: v1
```

Code Maid, on the other hand:

```
Invalid entry to install/download
Parameter name: entry
```

Ankh SVN gives me the same error as Code Maid. (Haven't used or updated Ankh SVN in quite some time, but I tried it to see if it worked)

I am not aware of any recent changes which I have done which could have caused this. The only thing which remotely comes to mind was installing VS11 Beta, but I'm fairly sure I've updated VS2010 extensions since then successfully.

Hopefully, I can avoid the *Dreaded Reinstall* ™

---

I appear not to be the only one with this problem: 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c/view/Discussions

---

Incidentally, I was able to update the extensions in question by downloading and executing the installers manually. But I would still like to know what's going on here, of course!

Answer (score 10):

Not really a full answer but I think I can help in regards to nuget issue:

1. In Control Panel -> Programs find and uninstall Nuget. (Make sure VS isn't running)
2. Go to http://nuget.org/ and click 'Install Nuget'
3. On the next page click Download.
4. Open the downloaded file (it should be associated with VS).
5. Follow the wizard.

This should install the latest version of nuget which means there will bo no update available. I'm not sure what will happen when next update is out.

I realise it's only a workaround.

Edit: Sorry, just noticed that you did exactly that.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the hotfix for that issue.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=38654

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Super! I'll absolutely accept once I can verify the fix. +1 in the meantime.

Comment: I installed that hotfix, and unfortunately the error remains. :(

Comment: Yep, it didn't work for me either. Another vote for just reinstalling the damn thing. :(

Comment: Doesn't work for VisualSVN update to 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Try loading DevEnv in [/SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and installing from there.  I can't tell you what's going on, but VS does get itself knotted sometimes, and just needs a helping hand.

Comment: Gave that a try today, since there's a new Tangible T4 Editor out, but it unfortunately didn't work :(

Comment: do you have the WP7 stuff installed?  What version of Nuget have you got?  I know with Nuget that you needed to run some command line thing in order to remove it from the WP7 registery, and that may be the same thing here with the other extensions...  Just a thought.

Comment: Hmm... no, I don't have any WP7 stuff installed that I know of. I'm still able to update extensions from their installers, though, so I'm going with that for now. :/

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues with NuGet especially in the earlier versions (pre 1.4 I noticed most).

1) If it's listed in Programs and Features, remove it there.
2) open "%PROGRAMFILES (X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions", if Nuget is listed, delete it.
3) go to your users directory (c:\users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0  if Nuget is listed in there.  Delete that.  Close/Open VS.  See if the error persists, if so.  You can try the /ResetAddin flag from the command line to see if something else was interfering.

If the error doesn't, re-install Nuget 1.7 (or latest) and hopefully all is well.

You using Telerik Extensions at all?  The Silverlight stuff hosed me royally.

Comment: My NuGet was the previously current. I have it updated now by using the installer outside of VS. No Telerik extensions at all installed.

Answer (score 0):

I get this when I have a [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) project open in my solution and go to update manage packages for the entire solution. If I right-click all of the WiX projects in my solution and unload the projects, then I can get update the NuGet packages fine. Then I reload the WiX projects.

I imagine it might occur for other "weird" project types as well. Something to try!